# SQL Server - Count the number of times the contents of a specified field repeat in a table

Tags: sql-server, count, distinct

What's the best way to 'SELECT' a 'DISTINCT' list of a field from a table / view (with 'WHERE' criteria) and alongside that count the number of times that that field content repeats in the table / view?

In other words, I have an initial view that looks a bit like this:

[image: Initial Table/View]

I'd like a single SQL query to filter it (SELECT...WHERE...) so that we are only considering records where [ORDER COMPLETE] = False and [PERSONAL] = Null...

[image: Filtered out any TRUE values]

...and then create a distinct list of names with counts of the number of times each name appears in the previous table:

[image: Distinct list of names with Count field]

*Displaying the [ORDER COMPLETE] and [PERSONAL] fields is redundant by this point and could be dropped to simplify.

I can do the steps individually as above, but struggling to get a single query to do it all... any help appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

-Tim

Comment: `SELECT <fields>, COUNT(*) FROM <table> WHERE <clauses> GROUP BY <fields>`

Comment: This looks like a very simple `COUNT(*)` query. Did you encounter some problem? Have you tried something that didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should just be the following

```
SELECT dbo.tblPerson.Person,
       COUNT(dbo.tblPerson.Person) AS Count
  FROM dbo.tblPerson
INNER JOIN dbo.tblNotifications ON dbo.tblPerson.PersonID = dbo.tblNotifications.AddresseeID
 WHERE dbo.tblNotifications.Complete = 'False'
   AND dbo.tblNotifications.Personal IS NULL
GROUP BY dbo.tblPerson.Person
ORDER BY COUNT(dbo.tblPerson.Person) DESC
```

You don't need your DISTINCT or TOP 100 PERCENT,

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/698340/6) is a simplified fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the code cleanup! I've just got one question: doesn't the last line:
    "ORDER BY COUNT(dbo.tblPerson.Person) DESC"

Just add unnecessary processing?
Given that we've already performed the COUNT and called it "Count" cant we just 
    "ORDER BY Count DESC"
?

Comment: You could just use the alias, but the SQL processor will not use the alias to "store" the result of the count and if they don't match perform the calculation again, it will figure it out the fastest way itself and only perform required operations once. The query plan will be identical in both cases. (Just tested this on a local database and the query plans are the same)

Answer (score 0):

Well I got downvoted into oblivion (probably for displaying the full extent of my own ignorance!), but just in case someone from the future experiences the same problem as me and stumbles across this question while Googling (or whatever verb you use for "searching all digitised human knowledge" in the distant future), here's some sanitised code of the query I managed to get to work in the  end - thanks to Mark Sinkinson's snippet for helping me realise the obvious...

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.tblPerson.Person, COUNT(dbo.tblPerson.Person) AS CountPerson
FROM     dbo.tblPerson INNER JOIN
dbo.tblNotifications ON dbo.tblPerson.PersonID = dbo.tblNotifications.AddresseeID
WHERE  (dbo.tblNotifications.Complete = 'False') AND (dbo.tblNotifications.Personal IS NULL)
GROUP BY dbo.tblPerson.Person
ORDER BY CountPerson DESC
```